# Returning pointer to intent(in) argument

Tags: c++, pointers, fortran, language-lawyer, immutability

I try to better understand the difference between `const` from C/C++ and `intent(in)` in Fortran in the context of classes.

**C++**:
If I `const` the implicit `this` argument to a member function and I return references to members of `this`, these references have to be `const T*`.
So the `const` does not only apply to the scope of the function call, but also extends to all references "created" in that function call.

**Fortran**: If I `intent(in)` the `this` argument of a member function the `intent(in)` only applies to the scope of the member function. I cannot mutate `this` inside the member function, but I can return a reference and modify `this` outside.

If I have the following more or less equivalent code for a Counter class in Fortran and C++ to test this and it seems to be correct.

```
#include <iostream>


class Counter {
    int val{};

public:
    auto next()
    {
        return val++;
    };

    const auto raw() const
    {
        const auto ptr = &val;
        return ptr;
    };
};

int main()
{
    Counter c{};
    std::cout << c.next() << "\n";
    std::cout << c.next() << "\n";

    auto ptr = c.raw();
    // does not compile, as it is expected
    *ptr = 0;
    std::cout << c.next() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

```
module counter_mod
    implicit none(type, external)
    private
    public :: Counter_t

    type :: Counter_t
        private
        integer :: val = 0
    contains
        procedure :: next
        procedure :: raw
    end type

contains

    integer function next(this)
        class(Counter_t), intent(inout) :: this
        next = this%val
        this%val = this%val + 1
    end function

    function raw(this) result(res)
        class(Counter_t), target, intent(in) :: this
        integer, pointer :: res
        ! This would be forbidden
        ! this%val = 5
        res => this%val
    end function
end module

program test_raw
    use counter_mod, only: Counter_t
    implicit none(type, external)

    type(Counter_t), target :: c
    integer, pointer :: ptr

    write(*, *) c%next()
    write(*, *) c%next()

    ptr => c%raw()
    ptr = 0
    write(*, *) c%next()
end program
```

Comment: you can return a non-const reference / pointer from a `const` method, just not to a member because they are const

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: My question is, if it is correct what I wrote.

Comment: `// does not compile as expected` why do you expect `*ptr = 0;` to compile fine? This somehow contradicts what you wrote before. You already know that is is not correct, no?

Comment: That was bad English on my part. It should be `// does not compile, as it is expected`

Comment: oh now I get it. It is "(does not compile) as expected"  not "does not (compile as expected)"   ;)

Comment: I don't understand your question, but maybe it relates to "but I can return a reference and modify `this` outside". `this` is local to the function and there's no "outside" where it exists. You can modify `c` in the main program, but that's a different entity.

Comment: you are basically asking two questions then. Is the C++ code correct and is the fortran code correct. Apart from the one line the C++ code looks ok, I cannot say anything about Fortran, last time I used it, it looked completely different

Comment: @mcocdawc To get more info, I've forwarded your question to the [Fortran discourse site](https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/about-a-const-read-only-reference-to-type-component/339) which is somewhat more oriented toward open questions and discussions. I think it will be great if you add comments also there (so that the readers will also understand the intent more clearly <-- pun intended :).

Comment: @roygvib thank you for forwarding my question. Yes I would really like to have pointers to `const` in Fortran as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments and answers regarding the C++ part of my question and consulting the Fortran 2008 standard, I think I can answer my own question:

**C++**:
It is not possible (without hacky tricks like `const_cast`) to create a `T*` pointer or `T&` reference to a `const T` variable of type `T`. The pointers/references have to be to `const` as well.
Hence: if `this` is a `const` argument to our member function, we are not allowed to return non-`const` pointers or references.

```
int& getVal() const {return val;};
```

```
int* getVal() const {return &val;};
```

would both not compile. So by declaring `this` as `const` we can give read-only access to our members. (And thanks to @Jean-Marc Volle I will use the first version.)

**Fortran**:
The underlying problem in Fortran is, that there are no pointers to `const` (`const T*`), but only `const` pointers (`T* const`). So it is not possible to give read-only access with a pointer to components of a type (members of a class in C++). The remaining question is between the difference of `const` and `intent(in)` and if it is possible to return a possibly mutating reference to an object (or its components) of `intent(in)`.

In the Fortran 2008 standard 5.3.10
it says:

> The INTENT (IN) attribute for a nonpointer dummy argument specifies that it shall neither be defined nor
> become undefined during the invocation and execution of the procedure. The INTENT (IN) attribute for a
> pointer dummy argument specifies that during the invocation and execution of the procedure its association shall
> not be changed except that it may become undefined if the target is deallocated other than through the pointer
> (16.5.2.5).

If I interpret it correctly, it is not allowed to mutate an `intent(in)` object, but it is possible to return a (possibly) mutating reference.

Comment: The meaning of 5.3.10 for pointers is that you are allowed to change the value of the target of the pointer but you cannot change the address where the pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ You do not need to return a `const pointer` you can simply return a `const reference`. This is the typical getter implementation eg:

const method means that the instance properties will not be modified by the method.

```
class Counter {
    int val{};

public:
    auto next()
    {
        return val++;
    };

    const int &getVal const
    {
        return val;
    };
};
```

In the exemple above, the getter could also return a copy of val. (no need for returning a const reference in that case).

Comment: > In the exemple above, the getter could also return a copy of val.

I know, but my member in reality is much larger.